# Monte Carlo Simulation for Pattern

Tags: r, montecarlo

I am writing a Monte Carlo simulation to check how many times y was not immediately next to another y. I conjured up a vector of 40 x's and 10 y's placed at random position in the vector. My goal is to calculate the probabilities of not having any adjacent y's in the vector. Here is what I tried:

```
nrep = 100000
count = 0
for (i in 1:nrep) {
  x = sample(c(rep('x', 40), c(rep('y', 10))))
  if (x[i]!=x[i+1] && x[i+1]!=x[i+2]) count = count + 1
}
print(count/nrep)
```

The result is a very small number, which doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` part is not correct. We can use `head`/`tail` to check for consecutive elements and see if there are `any` two consecutive `'y'`s in one iteration.

```
nrep = 100000
count = 0
set.seed(2020)

for (i in 1:nrep) {
  x = sample(rep(c('x', 'y'), c(40, 10)))
  if(any(head(x, -1) == 'y' & tail(x, -1) == 'y')) count = count + 1
}

count/nrep
#[1] 0.891
```

Comment: Hey @Ronak, I am not sure the head and tail functions are working as intended here; correct me as necessary. I think the way you wrote this code is checking for a group pattern against another group (i.e. the beginning of the vector vs. the end). I want to check for any non-adjacent y's and increment count by 1.

Comment: No..this is not checking beginning vs end. It is checking for consecutive elements meaning `count` will increment if two y's are together anywhere.  Try running this individually without loop. `x = sample(rep(c('x', 'y'), c(40, 10)))` Check `x` and then run `any(head(x, -1) == 'y' & tail(x, -1) == 'y')`. Compare the output of `head(1:10, -1)` vs `tail(1:10, -1)`

Comment: @Yoko BTW, the above gives probability of two adjacent y's occurring. If you want the opposite you can change the condition in `if` of just do  `1 - count/nrep` in the above.

Comment: yes I figure... just trying to understand what's going on in the head and tail steps

Comment: Do the steps also account for the element before? i.e. yyyx would increment count by 2... @Ronak

Comment: No..in each iteration count will be incremented only by 1 if the condition is satisfied. Meaning even if you have `yyyyxyyyyxy` count will be incremented only by 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222878/discussion-between-yoko-and-ronak-shah).